# How to Change App Name in About/Hide/Quit Menu

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

**I received this statement when I submitted my app for review:**

We noticed that your app name to be displayed on the App Store does not sufficiently match the name of the app displayed when installed on macOS.

App Store Connect Name: Jumping Jack 2

App Name when Installed: Jumping Jack 2

App Name when Launched: Jumping Jack 2

App Name in About/Hide/Quit Menu: GameTemplate

How can I change the App Name in the **About/Hide/Quit Menu**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `MainMenu.xib` or `Main.storyboard > Application Scene` depending on the age of your project.

Change the things that need changing. They got populated when you created the project.

[image]